# Preventing premature completion of an async pipeable operator in RxJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm creating [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) using RxJS 6, and am unclear about how to `complete()` the observer when the operation is *asynchronous*.

For a **synchronous** operation, the logic is simple. In the example below, all values from the source `Observable` will be passed to `observer.next()`, and after that `observer.complete()` is called.

```js
const syncOp = () => (source) =>
  new rxjs.Observable(observer => {
    return source.subscribe({
      next: (x) => observer.next(x),
      error: (e) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete()
    })
  });
  
rxjs.from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(syncOp()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js">
</script>
```

For an **asynchronous** operation, however, I'm a bit at a loss. In the example below, the asynchronous operation is represented by a call to `setTimeout()`. Obviously, `observer.complete()` will be called *before* any of the values are passed to `observer.next()`.

```js
const asyncOp = () => (source) =>
  new rxjs.Observable(observer => {
    return source.subscribe({
      next: (x) => setTimeout(() => observer.next(x), 100),
      error: (e) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => observer.complete()
    })
  });
  
rxjs.from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(asyncOp()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js">
</script>
```

So the question is: what is the idiomatic RxJS approach to make it so that the call to `observer.complete()` is only made after all values are asynchronously passed to `observer.next()`? Should I be manually keeping track of pending calls or is there a more "reactive" solution?

*(Note that the example above is a simplification of my actual code, and that the call to `setTimeout()` is meant to represent "any asynchronous operation". I'm looking for a general approach to dealing with async operations in pipeable operators, not advice on how to deal with delays or timeouts in RxJS.)*

Comment: I don't understand where's the problem. If you want to call `complete()` after all `next`s then put the `complete` call into `next` handler with some extra logic you need.

Comment: @martin Yes, that was the approach I was referring to when I said in my question *"Should I be manually keeping track of pending calls?"*. If there's no more idiomatic alternative, that's what I'll end up doing.

Comment: The most idiomatic, general and composable way is what @Picci proposed in his answer - do not create new observable from scratch and subscribe to it. Instead, just use built-in operators and let them do all subscription management for you.
If that does not work for you for some reason, please provider more details about your specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line of thought could be to restructure your `asyncOp` to use other operators such as `mergeMap`.

This is the code that reproduces your example using this approach

```
const asyncOp = () => source => source.pipe(mergeMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(100))));
from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(asyncOp1()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Whether this is something worth considering depends on what your `asyncOp` does. If it is asynchronous because it relies on some callback, like in case of https calls or reads from file system, than I think this approach can work since you can turn a callback based function into an Observable.

Comment: I would say even stronger: this approach should work in most real life situations.

Answer (score 1):

Still hoping to get input on a more reactive/idiomatic implementation, but below is what I decided to go with for the time being.

In essence, I'm just using a counter for in-flight operations (`pending`) and made it so that the operator completes only when the source observable completes (`completed`) and there are no pending operations (`!pending`).

```js
const asyncOp = () => (source) =>
  new rxjs.Observable(observer => {
    let pending = 0; // the number of in-flight operations
    let completed = false; // whether or not the source observable completed
    
    return source.subscribe({
      next: (x) => {
        pending++;
        
        setTimeout(() => {              
          observer.next(x);
          
          if (!--pending && completed) { // no ops pending and source completed
            observer.complete();
          }
        }, 100);
      },
      error: (e) => observer.error(err),
      complete: () => {
        completed = true;
        
        if (!pending) { // no ops pending
          observer.complete();
        }
      }
    })
  });
  
rxjs.from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(asyncOp()).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: It's as idiomatic as it gets. That's how operators work. And you need a lot more to make an async operator work as intended.

Comment: @abetteroliver using `setTimeout` not only is not idiomatic, but at least to some degree is wrong as not compatibile with schedulers and timeouts should be cleared when `unsubscribed`.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Your comments are well taken, but to be fair, as noted in the question, the call to `setTimeout()` is just a placeholder to indicate "any async operation".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I understand that, but an idiomatic way is to _upgrade_ an async operation to observable e.g. via `defer / bindCallback / bindNodeCallback / Observable.create` and use it to compose a bigger stream. In case of `setTimeout`, an idiomatic way would be to use one of: `timer`, `delay` or `delayWhen`. The biggest problem with the above snippet is that you can start an async operation with no option to cancel it. And it may easily result in weird behaviour and/or resources leak.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Yeah, I totally understand and agree. I've since refactored my code to use a pattern very similar to the one proposed in the answer provided by Picci. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @arturgrzesiak All you said is fine, but you miss the point. The question is not about an existing operation that you can "upgrade" somehow. You wrote _"use built-in operators"_ but they too had to be written once. Other reactive libraries offer useful operators that don't exist in RxJS. If you like them you need to implement them. So the question is how would you do that if the operator is async? Please note that I wrote _"you need a lot more to make an async operator work as intended"_.

Answer (score 0):

I created this runnable [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-51516606?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts) to show what i think should be done.

The idea here is to use `toArray()` to get all the values from source observable into an array. The code after `toArray()` is a single value (array).

Note: There are many ways (operators) to solve a problem, this is just an example based on what I understand from this question - that is both a good & bad thing about RxJS Observables. Hope this helps. :-)

Main demo code is:

```
// --- for each value, do the async service
of(...[1, 2, 3]).pipe(
  // let each value be processed by both async service...
  concatMap(no => myAsyncService$(no)),
  concatMap(no => myAsyncService2$(no)),

  // --- toArray() combines all the values (i.e. they completed)
  toArray(),

  // --- this will only be called once - with all completed values
  // --- testing: try commenting the toArray() to see the values as individual "next" value
  tap(val => {
    // see the combined values
    console.log(val)
  })
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was about async operations in custom pipeable operators. Maybe I misunderstand your solution, but I can't really find that in your code... Also, the `toArray()` approach is a little problematic in the sense that nothing is output as long as the source observable doesn't complete. This is not a problem when observing an array with 3 values, but it is a problem (for example) when listening to a websocket.

Comment: You have a point. I think i misunderstood your question and custom pipeable operators is something I have not tried. Hmm... I will have to rethink. Please ignore my answer.